# PHP Guzzle Get Request

Tags: php, ubuntu, guzzle

I have been trying to get a GET request from working but keep getting the 500 error.

I am at a loss on what is going on.

If i do the following it works fine:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://www.google.com',
]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'search', [
    'query' => ['q' => 'curl']
]);

echo $response->getBody();
?>
```

However I need to add custom headers so I found this little number here on Stackoverflow:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
// enter base url if needed
$url = "localhost:3000/Testing/read/log"; 
$headers = array('X-Foo' => 'Bar');

$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($url, array(
    "request.options" => array(
       "headers" => $headers
    )
));
?>
```

This errors out i bring up the console to see if the request gets made but nope it just errors out to the 500.

I'm not sure what is going on.

How do you structure a GEt request with guzzle with custom headers?

New GET request edited, still getting 500 error. If I make the request via POSTMAN it works fine.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$url = "http://localhost";
$headers = array('X-Foo' => 'Bar');

$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($url, array(
    "request.options" => array(
       "headers" => $headers
    )
));
$response = $client->request('GET','/Test/read');
echo $response;
?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://www.google.com',
]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'search', [
    'query' => ['q' => 'curl'],
    'headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'],
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://localhost/myservice/read',
]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'search', [
    'query' => ['q' => 'curl'],
    'headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'],
]);

echo $response->getBody();

Comment: It failed when I replaced google.com with my actual service

Comment: The google GET request works but it isn't the request i want to make, i was using it as an example to go off of but no luck

Comment: use $client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($url, array(
       "headers" => $headers
    )
);

Comment: Restructured to:


<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$url = "http://localhost";
$headers = array('X-Foo' => 'Bar');

$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($url, array(
    "request.options" => array(
       "headers" => $headers
    )
));
$response = $client->request('GET','/Test/read');
echo $response;
?>

Still throwing 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it wasn't that it wasn't working it was that PHP is server side language so when i was making the get request to a private ip address it failed because the machine in the cloud had no knowledge of that machine on the network...sorry all is good.
Thanks,